# Crossover function for genetic

Tags: artificial-intelligence, genetic-algorithm, evolutionary-algorithm

I am writing a Time table generator in java, using AI approaches to satisfy the hard constraints and help find an optimal solution. So far I have implemented and Iterative construction (a most-constrained first heuristic) and Simulated Annealing, and I'm in the process of implementing a genetic algorithm.

Some info on the problem, and how I represent it then : 
I have a set of events, rooms , features (that events require and rooms satisfy), students and slots
The problem consists in assigning to each event a slot and a room, such that no student is required to attend two events in one slot, all the rooms assigned fulfill the necessary requirements.

I have a grading function that for each set if assignments grades the soft constraint violations, thus the point is to minimize this.

The way I am implementing the GA is I start with a population generated by the iterative construction (which can leave events unassigned) and then do the normal steps: evaluate, select, cross, mutate and keep the best. Rinse and repeat.

My problem is that my solution appears to improve too little. No matter what I do, the populations tends to a random fitness and is stuck there. Note that this fitness always differ, but nevertheless a lower limit will appear.

I suspect that the problem is in my crossover function, and here is the logic behind it:

Two assignments are randomly chosen to be crossed. Lets call them assignments A and B. For all of B's events do the following procedure (the order B's events are selected is random):

Get the corresponding event in A and compare the assignment. 3 different situations might happen.

- If only one of them is unassigned and if it is possible to replicate 
  the other assignment on the child, this assignment is chosen.
- If both of them are assigned, but only one of them creates no
  conflicts    when assigning to the child, that one is chosen.
- If both of them are    assigned and none create conflict, on of
  them is     randomly chosen.

In any other case, the event is left unassigned.

This creates a child with some of the parent's assignments, some of the mother's, so it seems to me it is a valid function. Moreover, it does not break any hard constraints.

As for mutation, I am using the neighboring function of my SA to give me another assignment based on on of the children, and then replacing that child.

So again. With this setup, initial population of 100, the GA runs and always tends to stabilize at some random (high) fitness value. Can someone give me a pointer as to what could I possibly be doing wrong?

Thanks

Edit: Formatting and clear some things

Answer (score 0):

I think GA only makes sense if part of the solution (part of the vector) has a significance as a stand alone part of the solution, so that the crossover function integrates valid parts of a solution between two solution vectors. Much like a certain part of a DNA sequence controls or affects a specific aspect of the individual - eye color is one gene for example. In this problem however the different parts of the solution vector affect each other making the crossover almost meaningless. This results (my guess) in the algorithm converging on a single solution rather quickly with the different crossovers and mutations having only a negative affect on the fitness.

I dont believe GA is the right tool for this problem.

Comment: Hi. I suppose it might not be the best, but it can be done, as it is shown in several papers http://secretgeek.net/content/bambrilg.pdf,  http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/TR/1995/1995-8.pdf, and so on, so I would really like to see my implementation working...As it is right now it should converge to the best solution, with this crossover function, but clearly it doesn't so I am making some error =/

Answer (score 0):

If you could please provide the original problem statement, I will be able to give you a better solution. Here is my answer for the present moment.

A genetic algorithm is not the best tool to satisfy hard constraints. This is an assigment problem that can be solved using integer program, a special case of a linear program.

Linear programs allow users to minimize or maximize some goal modeled by an objective function (grading function). The objective function is defined by the sum of individual decisions (or decision variables) and the value or contribution to the objective function. Linear programs allow for your decision variables to be decimal values, but integer programs force the decision variables to be integer values.

So, what are your decisions? Your decisions are to assign students to slots. And these slots have features which events require and rooms satisfy.

In your case, you want to maximize the number of students that are assigned to a slot.

You also have constraints. In your case, a student may only attend at most one event.

The website below provides a good tutorial on how to model integer programs.

http://people.brunel.ac.uk/~mastjjb/jeb/or/moreip.html

For a java specific implementation, use the link below.

http://javailp.sourceforge.net/

```
SolverFactory factory = new SolverFactoryLpSolve(); // use lp_solve
factory.setParameter(Solver.VERBOSE, 0); 
factory.setParameter(Solver.TIMEOUT, 100); // set timeout to 100 seconds

/**
* Constructing a Problem: 
* Maximize: 143x+60y 
* Subject to: 
* 120x+210y <= 15000 
* 110x+30y <= 4000 
* x+y <= 75
* 
* With x,y being integers
* 
*/
Problem problem = new Problem();

Linear linear = new Linear();
linear.add(143, "x");
linear.add(60, "y");

problem.setObjective(linear, OptType.MAX);

linear = new Linear();
linear.add(120, "x");
linear.add(210, "y");

problem.add(linear, "<=", 15000);

linear = new Linear();
linear.add(110, "x");
linear.add(30, "y");

problem.add(linear, "<=", 4000);

linear = new Linear();
linear.add(1, "x");
linear.add(1, "y");

problem.add(linear, "<=", 75);

problem.setVarType("x", Integer.class);
problem.setVarType("y", Integer.class);

Solver solver = factory.get(); // you should use this solver only once for one problem
Result result = solver.solve(problem);

System.out.println(result);

/**
* Extend the problem with x <= 16 and solve it again
*/
problem.setVarUpperBound("x", 16);

solver = factory.get();
result = solver.solve(problem);

System.out.println(result);
// Results in the following output:

// Objective: 6266.0 {y=52, x=22}
// Objective: 5828.0 {y=59, x=16}
```

Comment: Hi.Thanks for your answer, but I am afraid I cannot use it. The point is to actually use some kind of AI algorithm on this problem, as we have previously tried other techniques (hence Simulated Annealing and GA).

Answer (score 0):

I would start by measuring what's going on directly. For example, what fraction of the assignments are falling under your "any other case" catch-all and therefore doing nothing?

Also, while we can't really tell from the information given, it doesn't seem any of your moves can do a "swap", which may be a problem. If a schedule is tightly constrained, then once you find something feasible, it's likely that you won't be able to just move a class from room A to room B, as room B will be in use. You'd need to consider ways of moving a class from A to B along with moving a class from B to A.

You can also sometimes improve things by allowing constraints to be violated. Instead of forbidding crossover from ever violating a constraint, you can allow it, but penalize the fitness in proportion to the "badness" of the violation.

Finally, it's possible that your other operators are the problem as well. If your selection and replacement operators are too aggressive, you can converge very quickly to something that's only slightly better than where you started. Once you converge, it's very difficult for mutations alone to kick you back out into a productive search.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong with GA for this problem, some people just hate Genetic Algorithms no matter what.

Here is what I would check:

First you mention that your GA stabilizes at a random "High" fitness value, but isn't this a good thing? Does "high" fitness correspond to good or bad in your case? It is possible you are favoring "High" fitness in one part of your code and "Low" fitness in another thus causing the seemingly random result.

I think you want to be a bit more careful about the logic behind your crossover operation. Basically there are many situations for all 3 cases where making any of those choices would not cause an increase in fitness at all of the crossed-over individual, but you are still using a "resource" (an assignment that could potentially be used for another class/student/etc.) I realize that a GA traditionally will make assignments via crossover that cause worse behavior, but you are already performing a bit of computation in the crossover phase anyway, why not choose one that actually will improve fitness or maybe don't cross at all?

Optional Comment to Consider : Although your iterative construction approach is quite interesting, this may cause you to have an overly complex Gene representation that could be causing problems with your crossover. Is it possible to model a single individual solution as an array (or 2D array) of bits or integers? Even if the array turns out to be very long, it may be worth it use a more simple crossover procedure. I recommend Googling "ga gene representation time tabling" you may find an approach that you like more and can more easily scale to many individuals (100 is a rather small population size for a GA, but I understand you are still testing, also how many generations?).

One final note, I am not sure what language you are working in but if it is Java and you don't NEED to code the GA by hand I would recommend taking a look at [ECJ](http://cs.gmu.edu/~eclab/projects/ecj/). Maybe even if you have to code by hand, it could help you develop your representation or breeding pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Newcomers to GA can make any of a number of standard mistakes:

- In general, when doing crossover, make sure that the child has some chance of inheriting that which made the parent or parents winner(s) in the first place. In other words, choose a genome representation where the "gene" fragments of the genome have meaningful mappings to the problem statement. A common mistake is to encode everything as a bitvector and then, in crossover, to split the bitvector at random places, splitting up the good thing the bitvector represented and thereby destroying the thing that made the individual float to the top as a good candidate. A vector of (limited) integers is likely to be a better choice, where integers can be replaced by mutation but not by crossover. Not preserving something (doesn't have to be 100%, but it has to be some aspect) of what made parents winners means you are essentially doing random search, which will perform no better than linear search.
- In general, use much less mutation than you might think. Mutation is there mainly to keep some diversity in the population. If your initial population doesn't contain anything with a fractional advantage, then your population is too small for the problem at hand and a high mutation rate will, in general, not help.
- In this specific case, your crossover function is too complicated. Do not ever put constraints aimed at keeping all solutions valid into the crossover. Instead the crossover function should be free to generate invalid solutions and it is the job of the goal function to *somewhat* (not *totally*) penalize the invalid solutions. If your GA works, then the final answers will not contain any invalid assignments, provided 100% valid assignments are at all possible. Insisting on validity in the crossover prevents valid solutions from taking shortcuts through invalid solutions to other and better valid solutions.

I would recommend anyone who thinks they have written a poorly performing GA to conduct the following test: Run the GA a few times, and note the number of generations it took to reach an acceptable result. Then replace the winner selection step and goal function (whatever you use - tournament, ranking, etc) with a random choice, and run it again. If you still converge roughly at the same speed as with the real evaluator/goal function then you didn't actually have a functioning GA. Many people who say GAs don't work have made some mistake in their code which means the GA converges as slowly as random search which is enough to turn anyone off from the technique.